# Create a query to calculate all purchases of customer number 100019. The output of this query should be order number, partno number, etc

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone who can read SQL tell me what I am doing wrong;

```
`Select s.orderno "Order Nbr", b.partno "Part Nbr", b.descript "Part Description", i.qty 
'Quantity', b.saleprice "Sale Price", concat('$', format( sum((b.saleprice*i.qty/ 
count(i.qty))),2) "Total Amount per Item"
-> From sales s inner join items i
->      On s.orderno = i.orderno
->      Inner join inventory b
->      On b.partno = i.partno
-> Where s.custno = '100019'
-> Order by 6;`
```

I have been on this for a while and cannot figure it out: I feel like logically I am doing the right thing but I keep getting an error. My brain hurts.

The question reads; "Create a query to calculate all purchases of customer number 100019. The output of this query should be order number, part number, part description, quantity, sale price, and total amount per Item (Format the result to currency and two decimal places)."

Comment: Hi @Christina V, welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is not clear in detail. A plain SQL query in the question will get us nowhere. Please provide the table schema with columns and their relationship, and let us know what is the expected result, what have you tried, and what is wrong.

Comment: You have missed a closing bracket in the concat statement.